# Restrict SPARQL query to a certain kind of Class

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, rdfs

I have a SPARQL query to select all resources that has the location "California" within the dbpedia database:

```
select distinct ?subj where {
 ?subj dbpprop:location dbpedia:California .
} LIMIT 100
```

Now my problem is to filter this results, so that I only get `?subj` that is a sub-class of a certain Class, e.g. `dbpedia:Public_company`.

I tried sth. like this:

```
select distinct ?subj where {
 ?subj a dbpedia:Public_company .
 ?subj dbpprop:location dbpedia:California .
} LIMIT 100
```

but this results in an empty result set.

How can I restrict the `?subj` to a be from a certain type of Class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is the correct way to restrict to instances of a certain class. If you get an empty result set, that simply means that there are no instances found. I briefly looked around in DBPedia and didn't encounter any instances of `dbpedia:Public_company`. Possibly you have a typo in the class name.

Comment: Thank you, you´re right, now it works for me :) Using dbpedia-owl:Organisation